# Limit number of rows fetching in a left outer join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, sql-order-by

I'm going to create a data model in oracle fusion applications. I need to create column `End_date` based on two tables in the query. So I used two methods.

1. Using a subquery:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT projects_A.end_date
          FROM projects_A, projects_B
         WHERE projects_A.p_id = projects_B.p_id
           AND rownum = 1)
```

2. Using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT projects_A.end_date
  FROM projects_A
  LEFT JOIN projects_B
    ON projects_A.p_id = projects_B.p_id
 WHERE rownum = 1
```

Here when I used a subquery, the query returns the results as expected. But when I use left outer join with `WHERE rownum = 1` the result is zero. Without `WHERE rownum = 1` it retrieves all the results. But I want only the first result. So how can I do that using left outer join? Thank you.

Comment: 1)What do you mean by *first result* ? 2)Can you please tag the version of the DBMS ?

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan 1) The first row of the results set 2) version is oracle database 22c

Comment: Please mention which table `end_date` column belongs to. And also the order in which you need to select the first result. Is it max date? or min date?

Comment: Would you please share some sample data with desired output!!!

Comment: due to which criteria are you telling *first*, how do you sort them, SQL represents unordered datasets.  Can you please edit the question with such details rather than commenting. Btw, there's no such version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want to bring a non-null `end_date` value(So, add `NULLS LAST`), but the sorting order is not determined yet(you might add a `DESC` to the end of the `ORDER BY` clause depending on this fact ), and use `FETCH` clause(the DB version is 12c+ *as understood from the comment*) with `ONLY` option to exclude ties as yo want to bring only single row.

So, you can use the following query :

```
SELECT A.end_date
  FROM projects_A A
  LEFT JOIN projects_B B
    ON A.p_id = B.p_id
 ORDER BY end_date NULLS LAST
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```